# How to give input from sensor to PID in matlab(mfile)

Tags: matlab

I am trying to implement the following system in matlab(mfile):[image: Vision based lane keeping control system]

My system has two portions Image processing(sensor) & control systems. The piece of code is:

```
clear,close
%your model and its input output
mot=tf(1,[1  1]),
model=ss(mot);
[F,h,c,d]=ssdata(model);
%your pid controller
r=pid(5,1/0.05,10)
sys.inputname='u'
sys.outputname='y'
Ci.inputname='e';
Ci.outputname='u';
som1 = sumblk('e = r - y');
%global model with all conneection
modelg=connect(som1,r,model,'r','y')
%simulation
step(modelg)
```

Above code is the model representing the PID then statespace and then its output as feedback but
I have to give input from my sensor(image processing part e.g 3) and compare it with my reference  value. I need to know where that input value will be adjusted in this code. Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The simulated output of the system is 'y', so what you will do is compare this 'y' with your sensor's output. This will then be used to get e, the actual error. You do this to have more knowledge about 'y', because a system description is never perfect. I guess this more a control systems related problem than an actual matlab problem or did I get something wrong?

Comment: Yes it is a control systems problem but I am having syntax issue. Suppose I am having a output form sensor as y1. I want to take average  of this value y1 and y(output of control systems) as (y+y1)/2. How to include this average in my code.

Comment: Sorry didn't get that.Well I never used these commands but by reading the help for 'connect' I'd say you need another block SYS2 which takes then y and the sensor data as input and you'll easily derive your feedback. Just check help connect. Sorry I can't tell you more.